# Does having separate javascript files used commonly by multiple HTML pages speed up page loads?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a project where a common javascript file is used by multiple views in the application.

Is there reason to believe that having this javascript file separate from the html will speed up the loading up of the pages?

If So How?

Comment: This is practically the most basic form of optimization you can perform, and its uses and effects are extremely well documented elsewhere.

Comment: @KhanhTO Please don't advertise your answers. We can all see it, you don't need to try to draw additional attention to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the JavaScript is in a seperate file the browser can cache it, so when the user visits the next web page he doesn't have to download the file anymore.

When you work with inline JavaScript the webserver sends the new webpage including inline JavaScript to the user. Is that clear? :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. The reasons:

- You could obfuscate the javascript file and reduce its size. One more benefit for this is that the script is more difficult to understand when it arrives at client side.
- The same javascript file is cached which reduces loading time.

Having separate javascript files does have other benefits:

- Your code is centralized in one place, when you need to change code, only change one place. If you embed it inside html, you have to change it in all your html.
- Obfuscating only the javascript file and reusing it.
- When you need to unit-test code in that file, you don't need to download your whole html file.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to obfuscate inline JavaScript?

Comment: @user2019515 The difference is that it's trivially easy to obfuscate external JavaScript, while doing so for inline JavaScript involves a *lot* of work.